# ATM program that loses data every execution

Tags: java

I am working on an ATM program. I have everything working and everything coded correctly. I press execute and can deposit/withdraw funds and have it be reflected with proper messages. When I hit execute again, everything is reset(account balances) and it shows nothing was withdrawn or deposited. How to I fix this? I was looking on here and thought maybe if I serialized some classes or something, it might work. It didn't.What can I do? When I hit execute, I want all of my deposits and withdrawals to still be effective. not lost.

Comment: "Everything works" .. apparently not. By "hit execute again" it sounds like you're running a *new* program? In that case I suspect you're not correctly saving persisting the amounts (ie. to a database). Each time a program runs it start from a 'blank slate'. (There is no persisted Smalltalk world equivalent.)

Comment: It works. But what I'm trying to ADD to my program is a way to keep the data after every execution.

Comment: *Save* the data from the previous execution and *load* it again on the next run. There are many ways to save: to a file, to a database, to some other persistent service, etc. Exactly 'how' the saving is done depends a bit on 'how' it *should* be persisted.

Comment: I am working in Eclipse and everything is reset when I run the program.

Comment: It's like a real-life ATM machine. It's always running, but if the machine is restarted, then the balances are reset and everybody has more money than they should.

Comment: public BankDatabase() 
 {
  accounts = new Account[ 2 ]; // just 2 accounts for testing
  accounts[ 0 ] = new Account( 12345, 54321, 10000.0, 12000.0);
  accounts[ 1 ] = new Account( 98765, 56789, 2000000.0, 20000.0);
 }

Comment: my code is too long. I have like 10 different' classes. I just didn't know if there was like a java.util that saved data if you implemented it or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a menu-driven program where you can see all the changes you need from your program, but this only exist for the lifetime of the running program, once you restart the program you will sure loose the all previous content, If you don't want to loose the data after every execution you need a consistent storage like a database or file where you can read n write or update each time you run it